# Want to have dedicated cache and want other processes to fetch data from this cache (Java)

Tags: java, caching

I am developing Java based jobs having some business logic which would run in its own jvm and would want to have a separate cache containing frequently accessed data from database , also running in its own jvm. The jobs need to access this cache instead of hitting database.

1. Which cache can I use? Ehcache , hazelcast or coherence?
2. How will jobs access this cache?  Basically how will I expose cache operations mostly fetch operations to the jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I only have some experience with EhCache, which served as a cache layer for Hibernate (or any other ORM) and it is transparent to the fetch operations, meaning that you don't have to explicitly activate it every time you run a DB query. EhCache inspects each query you run and if it sees the same query, with the same parameters, was run previously then it will hit the cache ,unless invalidated. However, EhCache runs on the same JVM as your java application with default configuration.

There is another solution since you wish to run the cache on a separate machine. A Database called Redis (https://redis.io/) is a great tool for building fast caches. it is a Document based, NOSQL store, which can run standalone or embedded on your cache JVM. i highly recommend you try it out (i am not affiliated with Redis in any way :) )